# OCR Software of .TIFF images with auto rotate support

Tags: windows, images, ocr, scanning

I am working with a person who has 30,000 or so scanned electrical schematics containing printed (non-handwritten) text in the .TIFF format. Many of the schematics were scanned out of orientation, but in no particular pattern (i.e. some are out of orientation by 90 degrees, others by 180 degrees).   He spends 30 minutes every day just rotating the images.

Is there any application (e.g. Adobe Acrobat Pro) that could rotate them automatically using OCR to make sure their text is facing right side up? I know there is a way to do it through the command line interface, but I'd really like to find an application with a GUI. The application would also have to work in batch (i.e. so I don't have to go through each file one by one). I work for a large corporation,  so cost is not as much of a concern as it would normally be.  The application would be runnable on Windows 7.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to develop your own application then you could look at the [LEADTOOLS OCR SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr). Using the LEADTOOLS libraries you will be able to auto rotate all of the pages in need of being rotated. During the OCR operation, you can call the [AutoPreProcess()](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/fo/leadtools.forms.ocr~leadtools.forms.ocr.iocrpage~autopreprocess.html) method

```
AutoPreprocess(OcrAutoPreprocessPageCommand.Rotate, null);
```

on each Ocr Page that is being added to the document. Here are a few lines of code that will show you how you can auto rotate a page.

```
// Create an instance of the engine
using (IOcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngineManager.CreateEngine(OcrEngineType.Advantage, false))
{
  // Start the engine using default parameters
  ocrEngine.Startup(null, null, null, LEAD_VARS.OcrAdvantageRuntimeDir);

  // Create an OCR document
  using (IOcrDocument ocrDocument = ocrEngine.DocumentManager.CreateDocument())
  {
     // Add this image to the document
     IOcrPage ocrPage = ocrDocument.Pages.AddPage(tifFileName, null);

     // Auto-preprocess it
     ocrPage.AutoPreprocess(OcrAutoPreprocessPageCommand.Rotate, null);

     // Recognize it and save it as PDF
     ocrPage.Recognize(null);
     ocrDocument.Save(pdfFileName, DocumentFormat.Pdf, null);
   }
  }
```

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this product

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat will auto rotate the document while OCR to correct orientation irrespective of current orientation (even if some are 90 or 180 or 270 out of orientation).
It may not correct the orientation for following cases
       1) If it doesn't recognize any text in the document
2)  If there is text in document of multiple orientations

You can use Acrobat DC trial version https://acrobat.adobe.com/in/en/free-trial-download.html
Steps to use:

1. Tools> Enhance Scan> In Multiple files
2. Select all files
3. Specify settings to run OCR and where to save all the documents

Answer (score 0):

Please try pdf2pdfocr (https://github.com/LeoFCardoso/pdf2pdfocr) with '-u' option for a single file.

You can get batch execution with some CMD or BASH script.

Disclaimer: I'm the pdf2pdfocr developer.